# Excel VBA - How to stop macro from working during public holiday

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently facing an issue whereby I need the macro to run from Monday to Saturday, **excluding** public holidays, since there are no reports to be sent out during PH. Below is my code:

```
Sub schedule()
If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) < 6 Then
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("14:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("16:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "broadcast"
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:00:00"), "broadcast"
End If
If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) = 6 Then
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("20:00:00"), "broadcast"
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "Public Holiday"?  Only ones that are national holidays?  Ones which are holidays in some states but not others?  Regional ones?  (i.e. do you have a list somewhere of which dates you consider to be "public holidays"?  If so, where is that list stored?)

Comment: @YowE3K When I mean "Public Holiday", I mean national holidays. For example, "Public Holidays" like Christmas Day, New Year Day etc. Thanks

Comment: Implement a list of dates you consider as holiday as an array. And implement as first lines something like a loop looping through an array containing all the holiday dates and if date matches a holiday `date` in the array then `exit sub`

Comment: @Peh Hi, do you hv the example of how to do it? Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement something like that at the start of your schedule

```
Dim arrHolidays As Variant, iDay As Variant
arrHolidays = Array(DateSerial(2017, 4, 25), DateSerial(2017, 4, 26)) 'Add all your holidays here

For Each iDay In arrHolidays
    If Date = iDay Then Exit Sub 'exit this sub if date is a holiday
Next
```

or instead of the for/each loop you can use `VBA.Filter` (as @RobinMackenzie pointed out it his comment).

```
Dim arrHolidays As Variant, iDay As Variant
arrHolidays = Array(DateSerial(2017, 4, 25), DateSerial(2017, 4, 26)) 'Add all your holidays here

If UBound(VBA.Filter(arrHolidays, Date)) >= 0 Then Exit Sub
```

All holidays need to be specified in the `arrHolidays`. If `Date` is a holiday then it will cancel execution and `Exit Sub`.

---

To load the holiday dates from a worksheet "Holidays" column A use

```
arrHolidays = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Holidays").Range("A:A").Value)
```

*Note: We need to transpose here to get a one-dimensional array out of that range.*

Comment: You can avoid the loop with `If UBound(VBA.Filter(arrHolidays, Date)) < 1 Then...`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Nice I didn't know about `VBA.Filter`. But it didn't work for me; are you sure about the `<1`? According to my tests it should be `If UBound(VBA.Filter(arrHolidays, Date)) >= 0 Then Exit Sub` because it is `-1` if the date is not within the array and `>=0` if the date is present at least once.

Comment: yes you are right - my line of code says 'no match' but for your answer you should do what you said and test `>=0` to say 'yes today is a public holiday'.

Comment: Thanks both. I will give it a try. Is my first time using VBA.Filter also :)

Comment: Anyway, is there a way to make it dynamic? For example, putting the dates in a worksheet and get the macro to reference from it?

Comment: @user7377729 I added loading from worksheet to my answer. Just add a worksheet called "Holidays" and enter all dates into column A.

Comment: @Peh: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it

Comment: Hi all, sorry for having a lot of questions. JUst one more question, will the use of 'exit sub' cause the macro to stop working the next day, meaning after the public holiday?

Comment: `Exit Sub` just jumps to the end of the sub without doing the stuff behind `Exit Sub` that's all.

Comment: @Peh: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry for having many questions, as I got a bit confused when my co-worker told me that 'End Sub' and 'Exit Sub' do the same thing.

Comment: @user7377729 basically he is right. Both end the sub immediately.

Comment: @Peh: What I mean is that he is afraid after exiting the sub, the macro will not work after the public holiday. Just want to clarify if it will still works after that.

Comment: @user7377729 This sub will end on a non holiday at the `end sub` statement and on a holiday at the `exit sub` statement so I see no difference beside it ends a bit earlier on holidays (not doing all the stuff). Anyway you can test it.